# Xcode 9.2 crashing after opening Product --> Profile

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, xcode9, macos-high-sierra

Xcode crashing on macOS High Sierra every time you go to Product --> Profile, or just press ⌘I.

Comment: SOP : Build, clean, remove Derived data, restart.

Comment: completely quite and restart your xcode.

Comment: Yes, thats true...I tried.....its crashing....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I found the problem. It is crashing when the device is set to Generic iOS device. Changing it to simulator/device solves it.